# Relation between speed of sound c and compressibility

Tags: thermodynamics

We know that
$c^2=\frac{\partial p}{\partial ρ}$

The adiabatic compressibility is defined as: $\beta_S=-\frac{1}{V}\frac{\partial V}{\partial p}$ such that the subscript "S" stands for "adiabatic"

How can I show that $c^2=\frac{1}{\rho \beta_S}$ ?

I tried replacing $V$ by $\frac{m}{\rho}$ but I get for $\beta_S=-\rho \frac{\partial \frac{1}{\rho}}{\partial p}$

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compressibility has some information about this

Answer (score 4):

With your result

\begin{equation}
\beta_S=-\rho \frac{\partial \frac{1}{\rho}}{\partial p}
\end{equation}

you're nearly there. All that is missing is a little mathematical trick. Simply make the substitution $f = \frac{1}{\rho}$ and use the chain rule to differentiate $f$ by $\rho$ and you see that:

\begin{equation}
  \frac{\partial f}{\partial \rho} = - \frac{1}{\rho^2} \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathrm{d} f = - \frac{1}{\rho^2} \mathrm{d} \rho \quad \Rightarrow \quad \mathrm{d} \frac{1}{\rho} = - \frac{1}{\rho^2} \mathrm{d} \rho \ .
\end{equation}

Using this and the definition of $c^2$ you get to the desired result:

\begin{equation}
\beta_S = -\rho \underbrace{\frac{\partial \frac{1}{\rho}}{\partial p}}_{= - \frac{\frac{1}{\rho^2} \partial \rho}{\partial p}} = 
\underbrace{(-\rho) (- \frac{1}{\rho^2})}_{= \frac{1}{\rho} } \underbrace{\frac{\partial \rho}{\partial p}}_{= \frac{1}{c^2}} \quad \Rightarrow \quad c^2 = \frac{1}{\rho \beta_S} \ .
\end{equation}